# What is the TrueTime API in Google's Spanner?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, distributed, google-cloud-spanner

I tried to read the document multiple times but failed to understand it. Can someone explain it in layman's terms?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384883/why-is-googles-truetime-api-hard-to-duplicate

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TrueTime is an API available at Google that directly exposes clock uncertainty.

Comparing to [standard datetime libraries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), instead of a particular timestamp, TrueTime's *now()* function returns an interval of time [earliest, latest].

It also provides two functions:

- *after(t)* returns true if t has definitely passed. E.g. *t < now().earliest*.
- *before(t)* returns true if t has definitely not arrived, or *t > now().latest*.

What's impressive, is that the implementation of *now()* returns intervals with generally small uncertainty.

Spanner uses TrueTime API to assign a commit timestamps to transactions in the way that it satisfies [external consistency](http://www.bailis.org/blog/linearizability-versus-serializability/): if a transaction *T1* commits before another transaction *T2* starts, then *T1*’s commit timestamp is smaller than *T2*’s.

More in the Spanner paper http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/spanner-osdi2012.pdf

Comment: So for a given time t, is possible that on server A before(t) is true and on server B that is false?