# How is "after" and "before" method implemented in Google Spanner truetime?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, google-cloud-spanner

According to their pager, it says "The TT.after() and TT.before() methods are convenience wrappers around TT.now()."

And according to [What is the TrueTime API in Google's Spanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274040/what-is-the-truetime-api-in-googles-spanner)

> It also provides two functions:
>
> 1. after(t) returns true if t has definitely passed. E.g. t < now().earliest.
> 2. before(t) returns true if t has definitely not arrived, or t > now().latest.

My question are:

1. On all servers in spanner, does `TT.now()` return the same result?
2. For a given time t, is possible that on server A `before(t)` is true and on server B is false?
3. Are they monotonic? e.g. On server A, `TT.after(t)` is true, sometime later, is it possible that `TT.after(t)` is false?

Comment: Since Google Cloud Spanner is proprietary, most of the information about the specifics of its implementation is internal. It is very likely that what you are looking for is outside the scope of the documentation available to the public, which means we wouldn’t be able to accurately answer the questions posed here.

In any case, is there a use case for this question? Are you implementing some service which relies on having this information in order to properly work?

Comment: @George I'm just curious. "before(t) returns true if t has definitely not arrived" means for that server or for the entire cluster?

Answer (score 3):

For details of how Truetime and Spanner work, look at section 3 of the [Spanner Whitpaper (1)](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub39966).

A discussion of how it could be implemented is in the question ["Why is Google's TrueTime API hard to duplicate?" (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384883/why-is-googles-truetime-api-hard-to-duplicate)

From the Spanner Whitepaper, a TrueTime value is not a single value but a timestamp *range* which is guaranteed to contain the absolute value. This range takes into account the potential clock drift - which in Google's network, with syncing the server clocks to the atomic/GPS reference time every 30secs is up to 7ms (from the whitepaper).

So if `TTstamp1` is the range `(t1_lo, t1_hi)` and `TTstamp2` is the range `(t2_lo, t2_hi)`, then `before()` and `after()` simply compare the extremes of these ranges to confirm that they do not overlap.

```
TTstamp1.before(TTValue2) = t1_hi < t2_lo
TTstamp1.after(TTValue2) = t1_lo > t2_hi
```

The answer to your questions are therefore:

1. No, `TT.now()` does not return the same result on all servers even if called at the exact same instant. However the values obtained on all servers when called at that instant will overlap each other, meaning that none of them are before nor after each other.
2. So for a given TrueTime `t`, it *is* technically possible that on server A `t.before(now)` is `true` and on server B `t.before(now)` is `false` due to the overlap comparison and the differences between the possible ranges. This is not an problem for Spanner because it will *wait* until there is no overlap (`t.before(now)==true`) before committing a transaction and storing its timestamp.

(Note: this information is derived from the public whitepapers and documentation)

Comment: In TT.after(t), t is of Type TTstamp instead of TTinterval

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture below , `TT.after(t)` is `TT.now().earliest > t`, so I think it's quite possible that `TT.before(t)` is `TT.now().latest < t`.

Try to answer my own question:

1. TT.now() does not return the same result on all servers at the same time.
2. Yes, it's possbile. Even though for case of `TT.after()`,this means time t has *definitely* passed only on some servers.
3. I don't know. If it is possbile, then it means t has *definitely* passed, and then not sure about that, which sounds a little weird

I think "definitely" in their description is a little misleading, they should simply be "higher than the latest"  or "lower than the earliest”

[image]